# Как при отведении курсора убрать background-color : rgba(0,0,0,0.6)?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Вот что у меня есть:

```
<div class="grid1">
<img src="img/cover1.jpg" class="cover" />
<div id="shell1"></div>
</div>

$('img').css({
'height' : grid_height,
'width' : grid_cover
});

$('#shell1').css({
'height' : grid_height,
'width' : grid_cover
});

$('.grid1').hover(
function() {
    $('#shell1').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : top_position + grid_height * 0 - 20,
        'left' : left_position - 20,
        'background-color' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
    });
},
function() {
    $('#shell1').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : top_position + grid_height * 0 - 20,
        'left' : left_position - 20,
        'background-color' : 'none'
    });
}
);
```

При наведении курсора на #shell1 наворачивается

```
 'background-color' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
```

А при отведении он все еще остается. Какой код написать для этого? Мой почему то не реагирует =/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.grid1').hover( function() {
    $('#shell1').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'background-color' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
    });
},
function() {
    $('#shell1').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'background-color' : ''
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

'none' - не значение для background-color. Используйте transparent.